# how to write controller in mvc4 with 2 forms in a single Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 forms in my LoginRrgister.chtml page as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Tests1", "Test", FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { id = "FormSearch1" }))
{ 
    <input type ="submit"  value="Filter1 " id="submit" />
}
```

and another form as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Tests2", "Test", FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { id = "FormSearch2" }))
{ 
    <input type ="submit"  value="Filter2 " id="save" />
}
```

so this time how to write  action result in controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Test1()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
    return View("sameViewForBoth");
}

[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
    return View("sameViewForBoth");
}
```